# SVG sprite sheet - Android

Tags: android

I am working on animating the character, the sprite sheet has around 100 images, and whole sprite sheet is saved as .svg file, I am using AndEngine for rendering the sprites, but still the character goes blur, can anyone plz help regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Which application are you using to save your .svg file? 
First, you may need to increase bit depth of your .svg file.
Second, You can define your Textures as BILINEAR_PREMULTIPLYALPHA in OnLoadResources() method.